# Is there any online compiler with executer that would compile apps that use GPU-specific C/C++ code?

Tags: c++, c, cuda, opencl, gpu

Generally I need some online compiler that can compile and execute provided program and output execution speed and other statistics. All program can be in one C file and it would use any GPU C/C++ lib provided. I want to compile at least C code. Does any GPU vendor provide any such compiler? Actually my problem is next - I have powerful CPU and weak GPU on my machine. I need to test some algorithms that are specific to GPUs and get statistics on there execution. I would like to test my programs any way possible so If there Is no such online GPU thing maybe there is any emulator that can output time and other statistics that I would get on some real GPUs? (meaning I would give it a program it would be executing it on my CPU but count time somehow as it was some GPU running).

So is it possible any how to test GPU specific programs not having GPU card mening on emulation software of somewhere in internet cloud?

Comment: You may want to look into OpenCL..

Comment: Pretty sure that *online emulation* of a GPU would be even slower than whatever crappy video card you already have... It might be time to upgrade if you're doing this type of development.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Amazon [EC2](http://aws.amazon.com/ec2) recently added support for "[GPU instances](http://aws.typepad.com/aws/2010/11/new-ec2-instance-type-the-cluster-gpu-instance.html)", which are normal HPC instances which come with two NVIDIA Tesla “Fermi” M2050 GPUs. You can SSH into these instances, install a compiler, and go to town with them.

It'll cost $2.10/hour (or $0.74/hour if you get a Reserved Instance for a longer block of time)

Comment: Is there much of a "barrier to entry" caused by AWS-specific stuff here? For example, where should I store my results and code etc once I decide to close down my instance? Do I have to learn about and set up S3 etc? Is it a pain to have to install the CUDA toolkit onto the instance every time before I can start working? I found it hard to find guides for this style of working.

Answer (score 4):

If it's an option at all, I'd strongly consider just getting the GPU card(s).

The low end of any given GPU family is usually pretty cheap, and you can make some reasonable performance extrapolations from that to the high end.

Answer (score 2):

<strike>If you get the CUDA developer tools and SDK from nVidia then you can build and run CUDA programs in emulation mode, where they just run on the host CPU instead of on the GPU. This is a great way to learn GPU programming basics before you start trying to get code to run on an actual GPU card.</strike>

---

#### UPDATE

Apparently emulation was [removed in CUDA 3.1](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/3_1/sdk/docs/CUDA_SDK_release_notes.txt).

Comment: Unfortunately, emulation was removed in CUDA 3.1: http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/3_1/sdk/docs/CUDA_SDK_release_notes.txt

Comment: That's a shame - it was quite a useful debugging tool as well.